# Group section date error in crystal report after deployed to a windows server 2008

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

1. This group section cannot be printed because its condition field is nonexistent or invalid. Format the section to choose another condition field. Error in File Detailed_CrystalReport {9C8154B9-5093-457C-9E6A-2A1D63E7E866}.rpt: Invalid group condition.

without group section report can correctly show report and with group section can correctly show in local computer only with visual studio

But with group section has error after deploy to new machine window server 2008
group section is date

my crystal report version is 2008, assembly version 12, CRDist x64

try 1: i try to delete the group date and run local, it can correctly show date,
but deploy to the new machine date is invisible

1. Group date is wrong the date have only 01/25/2011 however group date become 23/1/2011
   why group date is not 01/25/2011?

Comment: Where is your windows server hosted?  As in country, not isp

Answer (score 1):

I have just discovered a possible cause for this.. 
(I had a report that was showing something similar)

It turns out my GROUP section was on a date column and that there are extra options for dates.

see this group expert dialog from crystal developer 2008

[image: Change Group Options]

you'll notice you can show the dates grouped by various periods. (on the bottom of this list is also: hour, min, second and am/pm options)

in my case it was set to "each week" which starts form sunday.
that would also match your details.. so 25-jan is shown as 23-jan (the sunday before)

i think its a neat feature..  you just have to know it and be aware of it.